# Как задать условие в htaccess чтобы если в урл после второго слеша есть что либо редиректило на 404?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Как задать условие в `htaccess`, чтобы если в урл после второго слеша есть что либо, редиректило на 404?
Пример:

если в урл `https://123.ru/question/тут_есть_что_либо`, то редирект на 404.

Пробовал такой вариант, не подходит:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.+) /404.html
```

Comment: Сформулируйте точнее, что вам нужно: редирект на файл `404.html` или статус ответа `404 Not Found`?

Comment: редирект на файл 404.html

Comment: Учтите, что при простом редиректе сервер вернет статус `200 OK` и страницы будут проиндексированы поисковиками.

Comment: Ну нужно чтобы при переходе на https://123.ru/question/тут_есть_что_либо редиректило на https://123.ru/404.html

Comment: Вернее даже так чтобы при переходе на  123.ru/question/тут_есть_что_либо адрес остался такой же но страница открылась 404.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
# если запрос идет в папку question, то показать 404.html
RewriteRule ^question/.+ 404.html [L]
```

Comment: а если на сайте очень много папок допустим, нужно какое то универсальное решение

Comment: @OlegLuchnikov, замените `question` на `[^/]+` тогда.